# How do I preserve dtype when using numpy.reshape?

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, reshape, dtype

I have a numpy list of size 2020, which I want to transform to a (2,1010) array. I thought of doing this using `numpy.reshape`. The first row of the array should be of dtype `int`, and the second line of dtype `complex`. My list does consist of those correct dtypes (which is 1010 integers and 1010 complex numbers), but after `numpy.reshape` the whole array is of dtype `complex`. How can I transform my list to a 2x1010 array that preserves the correct datatypes?

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    freq = int(line[0])
    complexElement = float(line[1])+1j*float(line[2])
    freqs.append(int(freq))
    cplxs.append(complexElement)
joined_list = [*freqs, *cplxs]
test = np.reshape(joined_list, (2, i+1),order='C')
```

The output of `joined_list` is correct, but once I reshape, the data types are all complex.

Comment: It is not really clear how you ended up with a linear array of mixed types. Can you give a code example?

Comment: I appended two lists with different types, int for frequency and complex for S-parameters. It comes from a touchstone file.

Comment: `np.reshape` actually does `np.array(alist).reshape(2,-1)`.  It's the initial conversion to array that's making everything  complex.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay! Is there a way to work around this?